# Addings roles with Devise NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am getting the following error when trying to 'rake db:seed" after following the instructions to add roles with devise, using this [tutorial](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-a-default-role-to-a-User)

NoMethodError: undefined method `find_or_create_by_name' for # ...

My user model looks like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
     :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]
  #Roles an default role setup
  belongs_to :role


  before_create :set_default_role

  private
  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= Role.find_by_name('student')
  end
end
```

Seeds.rb

```
['student', 'teacher', 'moderator', 'admin'].each do |role|
  Role.find_or_create_by_name role
end
```

I get the following in the console when I run rake db:seed :

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `find_or_create_by_name' for #<Class:0x0000010137df78>
/Users/Dizzy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
/Users/Dizzy/Documents/MM/mandarinminds/db/seeds.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/Dizzy/Documents/MM/mandarinminds/db/seeds.rb:9:in `each'
/Users/Dizzy/Documents/MM/mandarinminds/db/seeds.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Dizzy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/Dizzy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/Users/Dizzy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Dizzy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/Dizzy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:543:in `load_seed'
/Users/Dizzy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:184:in `load_seed'
/Users/Dizzy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:173:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Can anyone shed some light on how the `find_or_create_by_name' is running into this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Better option would be in Rails 4:

Seeds.rb

```
['student', 'teacher', 'moderator', 'admin'].each do |role|
  Role.where(name: role).first_or_create
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`find_or_create_by_(attr_name)` is deprecated in Rails 4. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations

You need to use `find_or_create_by` and a hash argument instead:

```
Role.find_or_create_by name: role
```